# Windows API Codepack Backwards Compatibility on Windows XP

Tags: c#, backwards-compatibility, windows-api-code-pack

I don't have an XP machine handy.  If I use the Windows API Codepack to do something new to Vista/Win7 (e.g. "TaskDialog") in C#, how does it cope with running on Windows XP machines?

If I use the Codepack, have I effectively made my application only support Vista and later versions of Windows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look into "TaskDialog.cs", you will find that TastDialog's constructor includes the following lines:

```
// Throw PlatformNotSupportedException if the user is not running Vista or beyond
CoreHelpers.ThrowIfNotVista();
```

If you only include a reference to the Windows API Code Pack assembly, you will be fine. But using a feature which is not present on the OS currently running your application will throw an exception. To check if a feature is safe to call (i.e. supported on the current OS) most classes include a static `IsPlatformSupported` property.

So you could check `TaskDialog.IsPlatformSupported` first and call `MessageBox.Show()` instead if your OS doesn't support TaskDialogs.